# RewriteRule Equivalent

Tags: apache, .htaccess, configuration, apache2, configuration-files

What will be the equivalent of `RewriteRule` for the following?

```
Redirect permanent /a.html http://www.example.com/b/
```

Note that `a.html` also resides on the same domain e.g. *www.example.com*.

I find using the `Redirect` directive somehow troublesome because the ["destination" URL cannot use a relative path](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect).

Comment: Note that *a.html* is assumed to reside on the same server i.e. *http://www.example.com/*.

Comment: But "http: // www.example.com/b/" is *not* a relative URL?

Comment: @symcbean: *http:// www.example.com/b/* is a fully-qualified URL. I was looking for a solution that uses a relative path e.g. `/b/`.

Comment: Can one of you who closed this issue please explain why this question was closed? There are 7,000+ questions related to *.htaccess* and, correct me if I am wrong, this is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to the programming profession (quoting the FAQ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect a.html to the same domain but the /b/ directory i.e http://www.anydomain.com/a.html to http://www.anydomain.com/b/ add the following to your .htaccess file in the root of your domain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#reirect a.html to /b/ 
RewriteRule ^a.html$ b/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ulrich! Sorry, I didn't specify earlier that `a.html` is on the same domain; following the example, it's on *www.example.com*.

Comment: This is great. Specifying rewrite rules at the `.htaccess` level works both on HTTP and HTTPS; if it was at vhost, you would need to do the following: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8759906/583539