# Rewrite Rule to Work on HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite, https

I have this simple rewrite rule and it works properly under *http*:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.siku-siku\.com$
RewriteRule ^/work/all.html  /portfolio/ [L,R=301]
```

However, the rule doesn't take into effect when I was on *https*. I modified the rule set to the following but to no avail.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.siku-siku\.com$
RewriteRule ^/work/all.html  /portfolio/ [L,R=301]
```

How can I make that rule to work both on *http* and *https*? Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: Is it an .htaccess or a vhost? If a vhost, just put the rewrite rules in a separate file and source it in both vhosts

Comment: It's a vhost. @fge: Did you mean both vhost for non-ssl and ssl? Sorry, that might sound really basic but I am just starting to get familiar with Apache mod-rewrite.

Comment: Well, mod_rewrite directives are like any other, if you put them in another file and `Include` this file from another, it will do it. So yes, just write the rules in another file which you include in both the SSL and non SSL vhost (removing the `RewriteCond` on HTTPS).

Comment: +1 Thank you for the further clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apache uses a different vhost for ssl configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost _default_:443>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.siku-siku\.com$
  RewriteRule ^/work/all.html  /portfolio/ [L,R=301]
  ...
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

This link has an example for configuring Apache with SSL on Debian, but should be easy to extrapolate to whichever platform you are on http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/349