# https to http redirect not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I have a Wordpress installation where some https URIs have been picked up by Google - the site does not have an SSL certificate and I don't want one. As a result I'm trying to redirect from https to http, but it's not working. All I'm seeing in Google Chrome is the "Your connection is not private" message.

I've put the redirect at the top of the htaccess file and I can't work out why the url isn't redirecting to http so that the message doesn't appear? I've also tried it on other devices and browsers. Any ideas why the redirect isn't working?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RemoveHandler .php
AddType application/php5-fcgi php
Action application/php5-fcgi /cgi-bin/php5fcgi.fcgi
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#RewriteBase /bevanevemy.co.uk/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
#RewriteRule . /bevanevemy.co.uk/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot your R,L modifiers ( Redirect, Last) this way, it will go to the url and stop processing rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RemoveHandler .php
AddType application/php5-fcgi php
Action application/php5-fcgi /cgi-bin/php5fcgi.fcgi
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#RewriteBase /bevanevemy.co.uk/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
#RewriteRule . /bevanevemy.co.uk/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**EDIT** also, apache uses different file for ssl config. Maybe that is the problem

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8760123/3617531

Comment: Thanks, I've just added that and it's not making a difference.

Comment: i was also looking at on. <-- maybe On better? Did you run service apache restart when changing the config??

Comment: It's on a shared server...?

Comment: maybe adding the rule to a vhost_ssl you have there around? you should look for the virtual server with the 443. It seems to be a shared as metzed says

Answer (score 0):

Edit Your .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```