# Rewrite rules for https

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I would appreciate some help on this. I'm developing a dynamic cart in php and I'm having difficulty with the https side of mod rewrite. Or more understanding how to get clean urls working with https.

I have 1 rule to test in the `.httaccess` file for rewriting a url to `dispatcher.php`

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ dispatcher.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

When in internet explorer and I request a page of say:- http://www.example.com/somepage.html

It connects and the page it shows in the explorer bar is http://www.example.com/somepage.html so rewriterule is working with `dispatcher.php`

Now when do the same with https I get page not found 404. Ive tried everything. Am I overlooking the flow here and https does not rewrite to a new url masking another?

I need the https side to function the same way as the http if I can?

Comment: Unless you have a `RewriteCond` to exclude https then the rewrite rule will work with https as well. Have you confirmed that your apache https configuration is correct?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759906/rewrite-rule-to-work-on-http-and-https

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can manually access through explorer the https page of www.example.com/dispatcher.php The page shows up with the lock. would this still be a config issue?

Comment: Thank you Tristan you have helped me find a solution. Yes the virtual hosts file ssl needed to have in the directory structure AllowOverride All